# WPF charting DateTimeAxis issue?

Tags: wpf, datetime, charts, data-visualization

I created a graph with column series by using data visualization and in that i've taken DateTimeAxis as x-axis and i've one combo box with time intervals and based on selection of combo box i need to bind intervals into my graph at runtime. The problem is i'm getting error if i select intervals randomly like

```
var xAxis = countChart.ActualAxes.OfType<DateTimeAxis>().FirstOrDefault(ax => ax.Orientation == AxisOrientation.X);
xAxis.Minimum = DateTime.Parse(fromDt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
xAxis.Maximum = DateTime.Parse(toDt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

"The minimum value must be smaller than or equal to the maximum value."
```

so how can i overcome my problem plz help me.

Thanks,
@Nagaraju.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution my self..

reset max with tomorrow and min with yesterday.. 'll fix the issue.. like..

```
xAxis.Minimum = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                xAxis.Maximum = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check and modify the `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties as needed.

Don't use fallback values in binding, but control the dates set by yourself. If you're not using view model, you could use the setter logics in code-behind.

```
<charting:DateTimeAxis
    Orientation="X"
    IntervalType="{Binding IntervalType, FallbackValue=Years}"
    Interval="{Binding Interval}"
    Maximum="{Binding EndDate}"
    Minimum="{Binding StartDate}" />


public DateTime StartDate
{
    get { return _startDate; }
    set
    {
        if (EndDate < value)
        {
            EndDate = value;
        }

        // Set property and notify that property has changed
        //...
    }
}

private DateTime _endDate;
public DateTime EndDate
{
    get { return _endDate; }
    set
    {
        if (StartDate > value)
        {
           StartDate = value;
        }

        // Set property and notify that property has changed
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What may be happening here is the new Minimum value you are setting is larger than the old Maximum, so at the line xAxis.Minimum = .. you get an exception. Can you try this as a workaround (also to prove this theory)? Just change the order that you are setting the min/max on the XAxis.

So, use this:

```
xAxis.Maximum = DateTime.Parse(toDt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));  // Set max first
xAxis.Minimum = DateTime.Parse(fromDt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

instead of this:

```
xAxis.Minimum = DateTime.Parse(fromDt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
xAxis.Maximum = DateTime.Parse(toDt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

This ensures that the maximum is always larger, so long as your parsed toDT value is larger than the parsed fromDT

Best regards,

Comment: but in your case if previous minimum value is 10 and current maximum value is 7 then this time also i get an error right? like maximum value should be greater than minimum.

Comment: Correct. What I meant was say you have a range 10-20, then you set a range 30-40. At the instant you set 30, your min is > max, hence the exception. Try it, what result do you get?

Comment: can u plz tell me how can i set range. Also i'm reading values from datetimeaxis so when i try to change value of maximum immediately it giving me error by checking previous minimum value

Comment: Let me rephrase. 

What I meant was say you have xAxis.Minimum =10 and xAxis.Maximum=20, then you set xAxis.Minimum=30 and xAxis.Maximum=40. At the exact line of code where you set xAxis.Minimum=30, your min is > old max, hence the exception. Try chaging the order of setting, by calling xAxis.Maximum = DateTime.Parse(toDt.ToString("HH:mm:ss")) first, what result do you get?

Comment: but i setup this code in dispatcher time and incremented datetimeaxis by 5sec i.e. every 5 sec graph is moving from left to right so how to set min and max if graph moving left to right?